# How can I unite CheckBoxes to the rollable window?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I would like to unite checkboxes to one rollable window on LinearLayout. ( Sorry for my english ) 
Is here any way how to do it? I'm new in java. I have one condition on each checkbox.

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/emod1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/texty_v_menu" />

<!-- ... and 5 another checkBoxes... -->
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by rollable window? do you want a layout to collapse/expand based on checkbox selection?

Comment: When I click on the arrow or text CheckBoxes I would like to show/hide (collapse/expand) checkboxes bellow the CheckBoxes text. Is it possible ? I dont have reputation to add an img.

Comment: upload your image to some free servers and paste the url here

Comment: http://oi40.tinypic.com/2mocdww.jpg Here is the picture of my app. And I would like to show/hide checkboxes when text Above is clicked. the text is a TextView. @Waqas

Comment: @PatrikBorzecky See my answer. It will allow you to collapse or expand a view with a smooth transition

Answer (score 0):

You may call the following methods depending on the `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` of your `Checkbox`. As in the input parameter, provide the reference to the `View` that you would like to collapse/expand with a smooth transition.

```
/**
 * Allows a view to be collapsed and Gone with a smooth animation
 * @param v view to be collapsed and gone
 */
public static void collapseView(final View v) {
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    final Animation a = new Animation(){
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if(interpolatedTime == 1){
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    a.setDuration(500);
    v.startAnimation(a);
}


/**
 * Allows a collapsed and Gone view to be expanded and Visible
 * @param v view to be expanded and Visible
 */
public static void expandView(final View v) {
    v.measure(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targtetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation(){
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int)(targtetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    a.setDuration(500);
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```